# Opendoc link to a folder

Tags: business-objects, infoview

I'm using BO XI 3 and wanted to know if is possible to open an InfoView folder using an OpenDocument link?

For example, every item in InfoView has a CUID. So to open a web intelligence report I could do the following:

```
http://Server_name:6060/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?iDocID=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST&sIDType=CUID
```

Folders in InfoView also have a CUID, so is it possible to link to them using this method to take a user straight into the folder? Whenever I try I get an error message (**An error has occurred: An error occurred while trying to view the document**), is there a way around this?

I'm guessing the answer will be "OpenDocument is for **open**ing **documents**, not folders". Thought I'd ask anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so, for this reason:  the openDocument.jsp/.aspx command is really just *running* an object, so it's expecting either a report object, or an instance (in .rpt .pdf .rtf .xls, etc) that it can either render or open in another application.  Although a folder is a legitimate object w/ a CUID, it isn't something you "run/view" - rather it is something you browse.

Cheers!
Stefan

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/index?rid=/webcontent/uuid/5001d5de-f867-2b10-00bf-8d27683c85a0#section5